# JSON Query table

Tags: jquery, postgresql, jsonb, dbeaver

I have JSON table with some objects and I am trying to query the amount value in the object

```json
{
  "authorizations": [
    {
      "id": "d50",
      "type": "passed",
      "amount": 100,
      "fortId": 5050,
      "status": "GENERATED",
      "voided": false,
      "cardNumber": 3973,
      "expireDate": null,
      "description": "Success",
      "customerCode": "858585",
      "paymentMethod": "cash",
      "changeDatetime": null,
      "createDatetime": 000000000,
      "reservationCode": "202020DD",
      "authorizationCode": "D8787"
    },
    {
      "id": "d50",
      "type": "passed",
      "amount": 100,
      "fortId": 5050,
      "status": "GENERATED",
      "voided": false,
      "cardNumber": 3973,
      "expireDate": null,
      "description": "Success",
      "customerCode": "858585",
      "paymentMethod": "cash",
      "changeDatetime": null,
      "createDatetime": 000000000,
      "reservationCode": "202020DD",
      "authorizationCode": "D8787"
    }
  ],
}
```

I have tried the following three options, but none of these gives me the value of the object:

```
SELECT info @> 'authorizations:[{amount}]'
FROM idv.reservations;
```

```
SELECT info -> 'authorizations:[{amount}]'
FROM idv.reservations;
```

```
info -> ''authorizations' ->> 'amount'
FROM idv.reservations
```

Note that I am using DBeaver.

Comment: What your DB? PostgreSQL or MySQL? Please set correct tag

Comment: database is PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
select
    (jsonb_array_elements(info->'authorizations')->'amount')::int 
from idv.reservations;
```

If your column is `json` instead of `jsonb`, use `json_array_elements` instead.